# Battery pack and high current routing design for brushless DC motors on an unmanned ground vehicle (UGV) project

Tags: lithium-ion, brushless-dc-motor, battery-operated

- I am searching for an estimate for a custom battery pack configuration for powering the 4 BLDC motors (36 V 4.4 A). I think that BLDC motors may draw up to three times the current when the vehicle is loaded or on uphill. That means roughly 60 A in my use case. What specifications should my battery pack have if I want to run the vehicle on maximum current for 20 minutes?
- I'm also asking help in choosing a switching circuit controlled with low logic levels for use with a microcontroller.

Comment: There are 4 motors in the vehicle

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 3 x 4.4 A = 13.2 A is the maximum current:

- Nominal voltage: 36 V
- Effective capacity at end of life: 4.4 Ah
- Recommended nominal capacity: 6 Ah
- Type of cell: High power (not high capacity) LFP, such as 2 Ah 28650 cells
- Arrangement: 3P11S

Comment: Am I right about the fact that bldc motors draw about 3x the rated amps when stressed? The vehicle has 4 bldc motors.